# DAX - Sum values in many-to-many relationships

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I'm working in Excel, PowerPivot.

I have 2 tables. Table 1 has locations of inventory types. Notice that there can be several items of a type in a room:

| Kategory | Room | Serial number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pump | Room 1 | SN1 |
| Pump | Room 1 | SN2 |
| Pump | Room 2 | SN3 |
| Xray | Room 2 | SN5 |
| Xray | Room 3 | SN6 |
| Pump | Room 3 | SN4 |

Table 2 has which payers are responsible for each room. Note that several payers can SHARE paying for a room.

| Payer | Room | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | Room 1 | 70% |
| P2 | Room 1 | 30% |
| P3 | Room 2 | 100% |
| P2 | Room 3 | 100% |

I want to sum up "How many pumps should each payer pay for, based on shares of each room?"

The result for P1 should be "2 pumps in a room where P1 pays 70% = 1,4".

The result for P2 should be "2 pumps in room 1 x 30%, plus 1 pump in room 3 = 1,6"

I cannot make a direct relationship between the tables based on Room columns, as there are no unique values.

I've tried putting a table with unique room numbers in between Table 1 and Table 2, and creating a measure in Table 1

```
Share:=CALCULATE(SUM(Table2[Percent]);Table1)
```

[image]

but that doesn't give the expected result. Instead I get P1 = 0,7 (1 room x 70%) and P2 = 1,3 (1 room x 30% + 1 room 100%).

Is there a way I could (by DAX) create a table that contains joins of Table1 and Table 2, where Room(Table1)=Room(Table2)? Or something to the same effect?

The explanation is simplified. Of course the model contains lots of other columns that I want to use in data analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's possible to achieve this using a bridge table, though I don't see any great need. Try the following **measure**:

```
=
VAR T1 =
    SUMMARIZE (
        Table2,
        Table2[Room],
        Table2[Percent],
        "Number of Pumps",
            COUNTROWS (
                FILTER (
                    Table1,
                    Table1[Room] = MIN ( Table2[Room] )
                        && Table1[Kategory] = "Pump"
                )
            )
    )
RETURN
    SUMX ( T1, [Number of Pumps] * Table2[Percent] )
```

which can be incorporated into a Pivot Table along with the *Payer* field from *Table2*.